# How do I find out when a twilio call has actually been answered when using the JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm working on an in-browser call-centre application and am using the Twilio JavaScript SDK to achieve this. I'm using these instructions to get integrated: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device and specifically the example code.

When somebody starts the call I want to display a 'calling' animation, however whenever the person answers I want to change this to display a call timer.

From playing around with the SDK, I can only get the following method to fire when the actual call starts (not when they've answered):

```
Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {

});
```

Comment: I think you can't,you  have to manage it from you database by updating the callstatus values which would be given on the webhook that you had passed in the dial or client verb's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As John Ambrose says in the comments you can't get this directly from the JS SDK.

However, you can opt to receive a [webhook callback when the call is answered](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-parameter). You can choose when you get those callbacks using the [`StatusCallbackEvent` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-event-parameter), or you could receive all the events and check for the current [`CallStatus` of the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#request-parameters).

When you get that webhook, you would then need to push that to your front end using server sent events or web sockets.

Let me know if that helps.